# What font is this logo. - I have found similar but this one looks to be stretched horizontally and i need the same on

Tags: fonts

What font is this logo. - I have found similar but this one looks to be stretched horizontally and i need the same on

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's not stretched, it's Salaryman regular

[image]

The gradient color perhaps makes the darker parts seem to be slim, but it's an illusion.